# Pass an incremented counter to other Activity through Intent

Tags: android, android-studio, android-intent

I am using a custom adaptor where I used my counter.Look through the code.Here for counter I added one TextView to display and two buttons to add or remove.
You can figure out that I am trying to design typical cart :where you can add or remove items.Check the below code

```
public class MyCustom extends BaseAdapter{


static class ViewHolder{
    TextView tv1_price,tv2_cgory,tv3_prod,tv4_clog;
    TextView tv6_counter;
    ImageView imv1,imv2;
    Button btn2Minus,btn3Plus;
    public int count=0;

}

private Context context;
private static LayoutInflater layoutInflater=null;
String price[],categoryName[],productName[],catalogName[];

public MyCustom(Context context,String price[],String categoryName[],String productName[],String catalogName[]){
    this.context=context;
    this.price=price;
    this.categoryName=categoryName;
    this.productName=productName;
    this.catalogName=catalogName;
}


@Override
public int getCount() {
    return catalogName.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View v=convertView;
    final ViewHolder viewHolder;

    if(v==null){
        layoutInflater=(LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v=layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.mycustom,parent,false);

        viewHolder=new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.tv1_price=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        viewHolder.tv2_cgory=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        viewHolder.tv3_prod=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        viewHolder.tv4_clog=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textView4);
        viewHolder.imv1=(ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        viewHolder.imv2=(ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
        viewHolder.tv6_counter=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textView6);
        viewHolder.btn2Minus=(Button)v.findViewById(R.id.button2);
        viewHolder.btn3Plus=(Button)v.findViewById(R.id.button3);
        v.setTag(viewHolder);

    }

    else {
        viewHolder=(ViewHolder)v.getTag();
    }
    viewHolder.tv1_price.setText(price[position]);
    viewHolder.tv2_cgory.setText(categoryName[position]);
    viewHolder.tv3_prod.setText(productName[position]);
    viewHolder.tv4_clog.setText(catalogName[position]);



    viewHolder.imv2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Wait.......Checking Out", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            context.startActivity(new Intent(context,ShoppingCart.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)) ;
        }
    });

    viewHolder.btn3Plus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            viewHolder.count++;
            viewHolder.tv6_counter.setText(String.valueOf(viewHolder.count));

        }
    });

    viewHolder.btn2Minus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if(viewHolder.count>0) {
                viewHolder.count--;

                viewHolder.tv6_counter.setText(String.valueOf(viewHolder.count));
            }


        }
    });
    return v;
}
```

Here,you can my see logic to add or remove counter(to add or remove items) from cart.But here I hit a bump,don't know how to send counter value(individual row )to other activity through intent and how to receive them. I hope you understand my question !!if not add your comment down below,deeply appreciated.

Comment: you just want to send the counter value like 5,6 etc or the whole item object in cart

Comment: like a typical cart, want to send the update value of the counter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing value through the `intent` from one activity to another activity....

here i edit your code have look.......................

```
viewHolder.imv2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Wait.......Checking Out", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        context.startActivity(new Intent(context,ShoppingCart.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK).putExtra("counter",counter)) ;
    }
});
```

and get value in other activity like that..........

```
int counter=getIntent.getIntExtra(counter,0);//if counter have no value than it assign 0
```

enjoy coding..............................

Answer (score 1):

You can solve as per below answer :

Your code:

```
context.startActivity(new Intent(context,ShoppingCart.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)) ;
```

Replace MyCode:

```
context.startActivity(new Intent(context,ShoppingCart.class).putExtra("counter",viewHolder.count).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)) ;
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest below steps to share counter data to ur next activity:

1-declare a class variable in MyCustom class as:

```
int mCount=0;
```

2- Modify code as below to store value of count:

```
 viewHolder.btn3Plus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            viewHolder.count++;
            mCount=viewHolder.count;
```

viewHolder.tv6_counter.setText(String.valueOf(viewHolder.count));

```
        }
    });

    viewHolder.btn2Minus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if(viewHolder.count>0) {
                viewHolder.count--;
            mCount=viewHolder.count;

                viewHolder.tv6_counter.setText(String.valueOf(viewHolder.count));
            }


        }
    });
```

3- Send the value of mCount as IntentExtra like:

```
viewHolder.imv2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Wait.......Checking Out", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
Intent intent=new Intent(context, ShoppingCart.class);
                        intent.putExtra("CounterValue", mCount);
                        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                        startActivity(intent) ;
        }
    });
```

4- And then OnCreate of the ShoppingCart Activity , get the Value of mCount like:

```
 int CountExtra = getIntent().getIntExtra("CounterValue, 0);
```